# Cannot import property from __init__

Tags: python, import

I've a Python program with the following structure:

```
sdk
  -> jobs
    ->release
```

In the release folde I have a script called my_release.py. In that I'm trying to import a property called PROPERTY_1 from `sdk/__init__.py`. I tried adding `from sdk import PROPERTY_1`. When I run the script I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sdk'`. How do I import this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 1):

Python looks for modules in sys.path by default. If you want to import modules from a specific path take a look at this:
[Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: "_looks for modules only in the same directory_". Not quite. It looks in directories listed in `sys.path`, which happens to include, by default, the directory where the script is run. See [The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

Comment: Thanks for your correction, I modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be in the correct working directory. Just check it with `%pwd` magic command from ipython